# How to change data type of some elements in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to change the type of some elements in an (nested) array, and the only way I know is to run a for loop.

Please see the example below:

The data is of the form

```
var chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];
```

I would like to change to

```
var new_data = [
  [new Date("1980/01/23"), 95, 100, 98, 110],
  [new Date("1980/01/24"), 98, 98, 102, 103],
  [new Date("1980/01/25"), 90, 102, 95, 105],
  [new Date("1980/01/26"), 93, 95, 103, 103],
  [new Date("1980/01/27"), 94, 103, 104, 105],
];
```

The only way I come up with is a for loop

```
function transform(arr) {
  var new_arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var sub_arr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        sub_arr.push(new Date(arr[i][j]));
      } else {
        sub_arr.push(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
    new_arr.push(sub_arr);
  }
  return new_arr
}
alert(transform(chartdata));
```

Is there better way to achieve this?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @ Crazy Train, sorry for the imprecise words. I shall use 'efficient' or 'faster' way.

Comment: The answers you received below are not necessarily written with performance as the primary objective. As to what is fastest, only performance tests will tell you that, and it will vary between implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually yes, you are copying a lot of times the content of each inner array, using `map` and assigning the new value would work.

here you have a working example:

```js
var chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];

function transform(arr) {
  var new_arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var sub_arr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        sub_arr.push(new Date(arr[i][j]));
      } else {
        sub_arr.push(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
    new_arr.push(sub_arr);
  }
  return new_arr
}

function improvedTransform(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    item[0] = new Date(item[0]);
    return item;
  })
}
console.log(transform(chartdata));
console.log("-------");
console.log(improvedTransform(chartdata));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another:

```js
const chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];
const newData = chartdata.map(([dateStr, ...rest]) => [new Date(dateStr), ...rest]);
console.log(newData);
```

For ES5 compatibility, you won't be able to use rest/spread and arrow functions, so another option is:

```js
var chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];
var newData = chartdata.map(function(arr) {
  var date = new Date(arr[0]);
  return [date].concat(arr.slice(1));
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: `return [date, arr.slice(1)];` will give another nested array. `return [].concat(date, arr.slice(1))`

Answer (score 3):

Sure you could simply do this:

```
const chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];

const newData = chartdata.map(arr => {
  arr[0] = new Date(arr[0]);
  return arr;
});

console.log(newData);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array:

```
const newData = chartdata.map(([...arr]) => {
    arr[0] = new Date(arr[0]);
    return arr;
});
```

You can also do it in one line with param destructing like this:

```
const newData = chartdata.map(([date, ...rArr]) => [new Date(date), ...rArr]);
```

Comment: This will mutate the original array. You might as well use `forEach` instead

Comment: Yes it will in the first example, I'm assuming newData is all op cares about. If you care not to mutate, you can simple do `[...chartdata].map( ...`.

Comment: Your _"don't want to mutate the original"_ code is still mutating the original array.

Comment: Erm, this is why you (I) should always test your (my) code. Good catch! Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to create a new array from the existing one:

```js
var chartdata = [
  ["1980/01/23", 95, 100, 98, 110],
  ["1980/01/24", 98, 98, 102, 103],
  ["1980/01/25", 90, 102, 95, 105],
  ["1980/01/26", 93, 95, 103, 103],
  ["1980/01/27", 94, 103, 104, 105],
];

var new_data = chartdata.map(function(i){
  var date = new Date(i[0]);
  date = [date].concat(i.slice(1));
  return date;
})

console.log(new_data);
```

Comment: This modifies the original arrays. Put `console.log(chartdata)` at the end and you'll see.